# How to clear Redis cache using Redission when Redis deployed to 2 or more containers?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, redisson

In my Spring Boot project, I have one redis container deployed in Docker swarm cluster. I use it as Hibernate 2nd level cache for the application. I use Redisson client to manually clear the cache using the following code

```
Config config = new Config();
config.useSingleServer().setAddress("redis://" + redisProperties.getHost() + ":" + redisProperties.getPort());
RedissonClient redisson = Redisson.create(config);
redisson.getKeys().flushdb();
redisson.shutdown();
```

Now I want to scale it to multiple containers to load balance the requests. If I do that, how can I clear the cache in 2 or more containers at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [response](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/issues/3185#issuecomment-721639039) from Redisson author, clearing cache in one container, clears it in all containers